# Android Studio Freezes at Gradle Build

Tags: android, gradle

I just installed Android Studio on Windows 10, and tried to create my first App ("Hello World") from the Studio website. The program gets stuck (but computer remains responsive) at the "Gradle Build" step. I saw another post on this topic, referring to firewall issues, but no resolution. I turned off my firewall, but the problem persisted. Also, I looked on Task Manager and the Android Studio task was using 83% of memory (>480MB). Many thanks in advance if any ideas! Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you would be able to see more in console what does this build process does in background!

Comment: can you share your system configuration?

Comment: Do you have any anti virus in you system running

Comment: Anti-virus is Norton Security. Regarding configuration, I'm not sure how to paste picture here.

Comment: Anti-virus is Norton Security, Configuration is Windows 10-Home, 64-bit OS, x64 processor (Core i7-2677M). 4GB RAM. No proxy server involved.

Answer (score 0):

Close other applications, as we can see 83% memory equals 480 megabyte on your computer. Try freeing memory by closing other applications. Also list what is your RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly downloading the dependencies. Make sure you have a proper internet connection for gradle to download the dependeicies. If you are behind a proxy server configure the proxy in gradle.properties file before opening the project.